# Can you set a background image to an image?

Tags: html, css, image, background-image

I am trying to set a background image on an img tag. Is this possible?

My HTML:

```
<div id="content">
<img src="my-image.jpg" alt="image" class="img-shadow">
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
#content img {
    float:right;
    margin:0 0 15px 15px;
    border:4px solid #ffffff;
}
.img-shadow {
    background-image:url('img-shadow.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:0 232px;
}
```

Using Chrome's "Inspect Element" I can see the path to the background is correct. It's just not showing up in the browser. Below is the desired effect I am going for. By the way. the foreground image dimensions are 258x258 (with border) and the background-image dimensions are 258x40.

[image]

Comment: if you only need a shadow then look into CSS3 `box-shadow` property

Comment: @koala_dev sorry, I did not explain it very well. box-shadow is not the effect I am going for, though. See above image.

Comment: those shadows can also be reproduced using some fancy CSS3 `:after` and `box-shadow`

Comment: @koala_dev no necessity for css-level-3. You can still do it with :after and an image.

Comment: @MilchePatern right, if you don't mind the extra HTTP request, that in fact may be the best solution here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution using a container element and CSS `:after`

**[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tw2LX/3/)**

**HTML**

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="img-container">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/258x258" alt="image" class="img-shadow" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#content img {
    border:4px solid #ffffff;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.img-container{
    position: relative;
    display:inline-block;
}
.img-container:after {
    content: url('http://placehold.it/258x40');
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    right: 0;
}
```

**UPDATE**

And using CSS3 `box-shadow`

**[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tw2LX/4/)**

```
.img-container:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 90%;
    right: 0;
    height: 20px;
    width: 258px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(3deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(3deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(3deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(3deg);
    transform: rotate(3deg);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    box-shadow: 0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @koala_dev, you've been a lot of help!

Answer (score 5):

An image with no transparency and no padding will cover up its own background image.  Images having background images do work, provided there's some gap for the background image to show through.

Adding a padding around the image will suffice, if you just want the background image to show around the image.  You can then set a negative margin of the same size, if you don't like the padding taking up space.

Setting the background position to something other than `0 0` will NOT suffice; no matter what the background position is set to, the background will never extend beyond the area taken up by the element (including padding, but excluding border and margin).

Comment: Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SzsbC/2/ - I'd have put it in the answer, but apparently jsFiddle links aren't allowed without including code too.  I shall trust that there's a good reason.  (Linkrot, probably.)

Comment: While the image is solid, the background position is set to show below the image a little bit. See image above.

Comment: Background images can't show outside the area of the element, so you need to explicitly give the background image room (in the form of padding) if you want it to show outside the main image.

Answer (score 0):

yup. just make sure you set some `padding` so the background-image will peek through; demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jalbertbowdenii/p6fm4/1/

updated fiddle by removing all the padding. to get the desired "peek" effect set the two corners you are peeking out of with a little bit of padding and the others to 0. like so: http://jsfiddle.net/jalbertbowdenii/p6fm4/5/

Comment: `display: block` is not necessary.

Comment: @albert the background image position should make it peak out below the solid image. See the desired effect above.

Answer (score 0):

YES you can put a background image to an image.

```
.your-image{
    padding-bottom:18px; /* <-- height of texture image */
    background:transparent /* <-- to manage some-transparent.png don't set a bgColor */
    url(txtr-bottom-shadow-divider.png) /* <-- Your bottom right texture */
    no-repeat /* <--  */
    100% /* <-- align right */
    100% /* <-- align bottom */
    scroll  /* <-- avoid Yoda trolling for spam abuse. Joke */;
}
```

You noticed the padding? It is to display the background-texture, otherwise, the image will take 100% of available space (width and height) so you won't see anything.

Comment: Did you test using `:after`? I believe you may need a cotainer element for it to work and using padding will make the shadow appear inside the border

Comment: @koala_dev no need for an outter container. You're right, my example is not well suited for OP needs.

Answer (score -1):

Yes,

Here is the easiest way to do it:

In your CSS file

```
body
    {
    background-image:url('img-shadow.png'); 
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    background-position:center; 
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

It will set it for every page of your site

You do not need to use an IMG tag for background images. It is the best form to set your background image in the css, so that you can easily layer items on top of it. With a IMG tag  you need to make sure that everything you place ontop of it is absolute positioning, so it doesn't move. This is a huge pain. Good Luck

Comment: You're making too many assumptions + presenting a very strict solution. What if OP doesn't want this applied to all images, repeated, etc.?

Comment: @IdeoREX  Isn't 'body' supposed to be another .selector ?